# Не запускает ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Tags: python, termux

Запускаю через Termux **здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема возникает при запуске  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/storage/emulated/0/bot.py", line 2, in 
import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot' **

````
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.Telebot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardmarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Ҷустуҷуи дуст')
markup.add(item1)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Салом {0.first_name}! ХУШ ОМАДЕД БА БОТИ МО'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def bot_message(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(none_stop = True)   ```
````

Comment: Напишите в консоли pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ещё появилась это File "/storage/emulated/0/bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    bot = telebot.Telebot(config.TOKEN)                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'. Did you mean: 'TeleBot'?

Comment: Вы не добавили конфиг с токеном. И это уже другой вопрос

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn import config
```import config``` есть там я забыл копировать

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос с новой проблемой. Конкретно эта проблема решена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы получаете ошибку **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '*название модуля*'** то причина может быть в трёх вещах:

1. Модуль Python не установлен
2. Есть конфликт в названиях пакета и модуля
3. Есть конфликт зависимости модулей Python

В данном случае модуль не установлен.

Для решения данной проблемы нужно установить модуль **pyTelegramBotAPI**

Делается это с помощью менеджера пакетов **pip** который входит по умолчанию в Python 2.7.9 и Python 3.4 и выше

Для этого нужно написать в консоли команду

> pip install pyTelegramBotAPI